# How do I use a trim statement correctly?

Tags: java

I'm new to java and I'm wondering why I'm getting an unexpected type error.
Part causing the problem:

```
else if (statement.trim() = 0){
    response = "Please say something";
}
```

I'm making a chatbot so I'm using a `trim()` statement to detect if the input is just a space but I don't know how to get rid of the unexpected type error. I know there are other ways to do this but I need to use a trim statement, I just don't know how to do it correctly though.

Comment: Ahhhh thank you I just got it, it should be *statement.trim() == ""*

Comment: Since it returns the statement without the spaces

Comment: @mataray Sounds like you are on the right path

Comment: wait but it still doesn't work

Comment: @GBlodgett im confused,why is *statement.trim() == ""* not working?

Comment: `trim()` returns a `String` so you want to use `.equals()`

Comment: `else if(statement.trim().equals(""))`

Comment: @GBlodgett, if I just input a space, the trim should return the string "" which is equal to "" so why is it not responding with "Please say something"?

Comment: Are you wanting it to print to the console `"Please say something"`? Because then you'd have to print it. Otherwise look at my other comments about the difference between comparing with `==` and `.equals()`

Comment: Ok yeah that's what I was thinking, I just forgot about it since you told me to use ==, thank you

Comment: No you were right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
else if (statement.trim().equals(""){
        response = "Please say something";
    }
```

You should be using `.equals` instead of `==` because the latter checks if they are the same object, which is not the case and will never be true. A blank String can be represented by `""`.